# Filter DataFrame based on partial matching string from list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with lots of categories. Here list of some of them

```
Bank 

(0827) ОСП                                  
(0283) Банк ВТБ (ПАО)                       
(0822) ОСИП_ПЕНСЫ                           
(0260) АО Тинькофф Банк                     
(0755) ПАО Совкомбанк
```

I want to filter dataframe based on string matching. I don't want to pass entire row name, i wanna pass something like ['Совкомбанк', 'Тинькофф']. The expecting result of this is :

```
(0260) АО Тинькофф Банк                     
(0755) ПАО Совкомбанк
```

I tried  `df = df[df[column_name].isin(values)]` but i didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.isin` will check for exact match. What you are looking for is `.str.contains`:

```
match_strs =  ['Совкомбанк', 'Тинькофф']
df = df[df[column_name].str.contains("(" + "|".join(match_strs) + ")")]
```

You can have custom regular expressions within `str.contains(...)` to search for whatever you want.

Comment: You don't even need the parentheses around the pattern for `.contains`, mostly that's for `extract` with multiple possible values. +1.

Comment: @ALollz That's true, but having it won't harm, and it can be handy if the search term is a phrase rather than a single word.

Comment: Well no, I don't think the parenthesis don't change anything about the pattern. But they will result in a warning: `This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.`

Comment: @ALollz Maybe I was using it wrong :P, I knew about the warning, but it at least works for my cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just pass the `names` you have to clean up the `Bank` column

`df[df['Bank'].str.split(' ').str.get(1).isin(values)]`